# Symfony: Provide message for security voter that denies access?

Tags: symfony

I'm working on security for an API. Some things that I check on each request are:

1. Is the user's IP address whitelisted for access
2. Is the user's account expired
3. Is the user's rate limit exceeded for the day?

It seems like I should use a security Voter, perhaps one for each of these things, and return `VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED` when an access check fails.

However, I want to provide a message to the user in the API response that provides some indication as to WHY their request was denied. I cannot do this with a security voter.

My current workaround is to listen to the kernel `controller` event, perform my access checks, and then throw an explicit `AccessDeniedException` with my specific message if the check fails.

Is that a good way to handle this shortcoming? Maybe there's a way to do this within the security voter that I'm overlooking?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html#how-to-use-the-voter-in-a-controller  does this one works for you?

Comment: Perhaps a variation of that. I could create three separate voters, then modify my kernel controller event listener to execute those voters, so I don't have to include the code in each action.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but I just had the same problem and **found a solution that works like a charm**.

PS: I'm using symfony 3.4.4

The idea is to pass the `RequestStack` to the voter (constructor injection) then get the session and add a message in the flashBag to be displayed after that.

The voter constructor:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class ContactVoter extends Voter {

private $requestStack;

function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack) {
    $this->requestStack= $requestStack;
}
```

If you are not using autowire and want to pass it as an argument in the service.yml you can use `arguments: [@request_stack]`

Inside the voter, the function that decide the permissions:

```
if ( 'Your_Access_Denied_Condition') {
    $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('danger', 'Your message !');
    return false ;
}
```

The template to display the message

```
{% if app.request.hasPreviousSession %}
            {% for type, messages in app.session.flashbag.all() %}
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <div class="alert alert-{{ type }}">
                        {{ message|trans({}, 'messages') }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
```

If you dont want to use the flashBag, you can use the same logic to throw a customized exception with a specific message, catch it with a listener and display the message you want.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've had the same problem as you did. There is no easy way for this one you'd have to overwrite the default `SecurityListener` of Symfony `Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener` with something in those lines:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener;

class MySecurityListener extends SecurityListener 
{
    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$configuration = $request->attributes->get('_acme_security')) {
            return;
        }

        // trick to simulate one security configuration (all in one class/method).
        $request->attributes->set('_security', new SecurityConfiguration($configuration));

        if (!$this->language->evaluate($configuration->getExpression(), $this->getVariables($request))) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException(sprintf($configuration->getMessage());
        }

        parent::onKernelController($event);
    }
}
```

On top of that you'll need to extend `Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security` like so:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security as SensioSecurity;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class Security extends SensioSecurity
{
    protected $message;

    public function getAliasName()
    {
        return 'acme_security';
    }

    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }
}
```

This above will allow you to add a `message` property to your controller annotation and that will be used if there is AccessDenied exception.

And here how to configure your security listener in Yaml:

```
  acme.security.listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener
    parent: sensio_framework_extra.security.listener
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put httpException like

```php
throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('Error, you can access here');
```

You can check httpException type here :
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/7.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Exception/HttpException.php

You can read apiplatform doc about error handling, Exception status code decision :
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/errors/

and read symfony documentation
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html#changing-the-message-and-status-code-returned
If the status code is different than 403, an HttpException will be thrown instead.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, especially if the original post already contained this solution and asked for a different one

Comment: Please, read my answers, especially http part of the exception name.

Is not the same error, OP use AccessDeniedException, but he will use AccessDeniedHttpException.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should using a different exception make a difference, especially if the OP asks whether using an exception is a good idea after all?

Comment: I updated my answer as best I could.
Can you update your vote?
I don't speak English very well, the solution is in the documentation, I wrote an answer to update an 8 year old question for other users, although the answer is not perfect, I don't think deserve to be punished.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer**. Posting a link to the documentation does not help others to understand **why** your solution works

Comment: You kiding me ? 
Do you want me to explain and go further than the official documentation?

I'm starting to understand why users increasingly prefer AI, rather than so.

Reading the documentation helps everyone, projects, forums, developers...

As they say at my work, hours of debugging can save you 5 minutes of reading documentation.